Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-\overline{H}_{n-1}^{(2)}\right)^2=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}$
It is suggested a typical sum involving alternative harmonic-numbers
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-\overline{H}_{n-1}^{(2)}\right)^2=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}
$$
where the alternative harmonic-numbers is defined as
$$
\overline{H}_{n}^{(r)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^r} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^r} - \frac{1}{2^{r-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} \frac{1}{k^r}
$$
for $\overline{H}_{\infty}^{(2)} = \zeta(2)/2$, the terms also writes as the tail series of alternative harmonic sum, namely
$$
\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-\overline{H}_{n-1}^{(2)} = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}
$$
I tried to find the generating function of this sum, yet no more insight to get a result.
Moreover, such clean result may suggest a more elegant proof that I missed, so I post it here.
As always, thanks in advance for any help.

Summation by parts gives
$$\begin{align}& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)\left(\eta(2)-\overline{H}^{(2)}_{n-1}\right)^2 \\ =& -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left(2\eta(2)-2\overline{H}^{(2)}_n +\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}\right)\\ = &\zeta(2)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\left(\eta(2)-\overline{H}^{(2)}_n\right)\\ = & \zeta(2)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2(n+1)^2} \\ = & \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}\end{align}$$
Conclusion: Summation by part is underrated

Yeah. When I realize that it just so obvious when you do sum by parts.
